After New Outlook recent updates, Outlook Add-ins behaves unexpectedly showing broken UI and Confusing Dialog
I have developed Outlook Add-ins and released it in production. Everything is working fine as expected. However in the past few days, there are unexpected behaviors, after clicking Send button, Add-ins start processing, then Outlook UI is broken as shown below.

Additionally, when Add-ins is taking longer time than expected, it will show warning dialog with the broken UI as shown below.

Moreover, if Add-ins is trying to close the email, it will show unexpected prompt dialog as shown below.

I found in the documentation that this behavior can happen in Classic Outlook Desktop when mail is closed during on-send process. However, in the current testing I am using New Outlook application (not Classic Outlook Desktop). Does anyone know how to address this issue?
